# Is it ok to paint Hindu deities even though you are another faith

Tags: other-religions, ethics

There are a mix of Hindus and Sikhs in our family.

Am really fascinating by Ramayana, Mahabharata, what Hinduism really is (philosophy, way of life)

I am more comfortable and gravitate towards Sikhism (interesting there are lot of references to Hinduism in Shri Guru Granth Sahib, and several beliefs are similar to Hinduism, such as Karma, reincarnation)

I also love to paint, particularly anything related to Indian subcontinent.

Several of my coworkers appreciate my paintings. One of them showed me photo of very old painting of Lord Ganesh, Mother Parvati and Bholenath.

Very beautiful photo. Quite detailed and colorful.

Question: I would like to paint this and gift it to that coworker. Is it ok to do so even though I am not Hindu. Is there anything in Hindu faith I need to be aware of if I do this?

Comment: yes. (1) if you keep it respectful , then its okay (2) if you make it with devotion to deity, then its good . For reference, just see the devotion with which sculptors and idol makers make such beautiful idols and temples since generations.

Comment: Yes, of course I shall keep it respectful. And I do respect these great beings (or metaphors of nature, depending on ones belief) who existed thousands of years ago. I just love the awe and beauty of India's culture and am optimistic about India's future.

Comment: personal advice not allowed on this forum. And why would it not be ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes definitely you can. But you must have to be respectful to their dignity because now a days people are adding their own fantasies while painting which is fair but not while painting God and Goddess.

Comment: Certainly will have utmost respect.

Comment: Give scriptural references . Your answer is not an answer, it is a comment. Use comment boxes to comment. Answer boxes are for answering, not commenting

Answer (score 2):

If it is your profession, you like it and portray the painting to evoke Bhakthi what is wrong?

illustrations commissioned by ISKON in Bhagavatha are all not made by Hindus. When Greek architure was influecing Hindu traditional iconography (Gandhara style) it was accepted, assimilated and even later admired.

For such works of art I (for one) think there is a big cultural as well as commercial future as it shows respect for other religion and art forms  in diversity.

Comment: I paint for enjoyment :-)

Comment: Use comment boxes to comment. Answer boxes are to be used to answer only.